# several segmentation fault for different processes

Tags: segmentation-fault

I have installed ubuntu desktop 18.04.4 recently and having problems of several segmentation faults from running different programs such as python, nano.

The syslog looks like this:

```
Feb  4 18:50:04 dmcb-System-Product-Name kernel: [ 5368.279040] nano[12154]: segfault at 56956c2ce1e0 ip 000056056aa019d9 sp 00007ffd0396c478 error 4 in nano[56056a9f2000+3b000]
Feb  4 19:37:52 dmcb-System-Product-Name kernel: [ 8236.744267] sshd[12526]: segfault at 7fa9094e29d8 ip 00007fed092ec749 sp 00007ffde26ffaf0 error 4 in ld-2.27.so[7fed092db000+27000]
Feb  4 19:37:52 dmcb-System-Product-Name kernel: [ 8237.023587] apport[12529]: segfault at 80009d45e9 ip 000000000059cc34 sp 00007ffd65dbeda8 error 4 in python3.6[400000+3b4000]
Feb  5 07:22:02 dmcb-System-Product-Name kernel: [ 4105.284518] gsd-xsettings[8718]: segfault at 7f1d280095ac ip 00007f3d3f6001d8 sp 00007ffe6b79a5f0 error 4 in libglib-2.0.so.0.5600.4[7f3d3f5b4000+114000]
```

I am currently debugging this error but is not sure what the problem is.
Since segmentation fault comes from different processes randomly, I am supposing hardware is the cause.
Some insights would really help. Thank you.

EDIT:

This is the result of sudo lshw -C memory:

```
guest@combio172-System:~$ sudo lshw -C memory
[sudo] password for guest:
  *-firmware
       description: BIOS
       vendor: American Megatrends Inc.
       physical id: 0
       version: 1602
       date: 06/28/2018
       size: 64KiB
       capacity: 15MiB
       capabilities: pci apm upgrade shadowing cdboot bootselect socketedrom edd int13floppy1200 int13floppy720 int13floppy2880 int5printscreen int9keyboard int14serial int17printer acpi usb biosbootspecification uefi
  *-memory
       description: System Memory
       physical id: 45
       slot: System board or motherboard
       size: 64GiB
     *-bank:0
          description: DIMM DDR4 Synchronous Unbuffered (Unregistered) 2667 MHz (0.4 ns)
          product: M378A2K43CB1-CTD
          vendor: Samsung
          physical id: 0
          serial: 71093B5C
          slot: ChannelA-DIMM1
          size: 16GiB
          width: 64 bits
          clock: 2667MHz (0.4ns)
     *-bank:1
          description: DIMM DDR4 Synchronous Unbuffered (Unregistered) 2667 MHz (0.4 ns)
          product: M378A2K43CB1-CTD
          vendor: Samsung
          physical id: 1
          serial: 71093B5B
          slot: ChannelA-DIMM2
          size: 16GiB
          width: 64 bits
          clock: 2667MHz (0.4ns)
     *-bank:2
          description: DIMM DDR4 Synchronous Unbuffered (Unregistered) 2667 MHz (0.4 ns)
          product: M378A2K43CB1-CTD
          vendor: Samsung
          physical id: 2
          serial: 71093B6A
          slot: ChannelB-DIMM1
          size: 16GiB
          width: 64 bits
          clock: 2667MHz (0.4ns)
     *-bank:3
          description: DIMM DDR4 Synchronous Unbuffered (Unregistered) 2667 MHz (0.4 ns)
          product: M378A2K43CB1-CTD
          vendor: Samsung
          physical id: 3
          serial: 71093B7F
          slot: ChannelB-DIMM2
          size: 16GiB
          width: 64 bits
          clock: 2667MHz (0.4ns)
  *-cache:0
       description: L1 cache
       physical id: 4b
       slot: L1 Cache
       size: 384KiB
       capacity: 384KiB
       capabilities: synchronous internal write-back unified
       configuration: level=1
  *-cache:1
       description: L2 cache
       physical id: 4c
       slot: L2 Cache
       size: 1536KiB
       capacity: 1536KiB
       capabilities: synchronous internal write-back unified
       configuration: level=2
  *-cache:2
       description: L3 cache
       physical id: 4d
       slot: L3 Cache
       size: 12MiB
       capacity: 12MiB
       capabilities: synchronous internal write-back unified
       configuration: level=3
  *-memory UNCLAIMED
       description: Memory controller
       product: 200 Series/Z370 Chipset Family Power Management Controller
       vendor: Intel Corporation
       physical id: 1f.2
       bus info: pci@0000:00:1f.2
       version: 00
       width: 32 bits
       clock: 33MHz (30.3ns)
       capabilities: bus_master
       configuration: latency=0
       resources: memory:df344000-df347fff
```

and free -h:

```
guest@combio172-System:~$ free -h
              total        used        free      shared  buff/cache   available
Mem:            62G        1.5G         58G         79M        2.5G         60G
Swap:          189M          0B        189M
```

Comment: @guiverc I did not install anything new after apt-get update and upgrade. And I formatted the disk before I installed ubuntu 18.04.4.

Comment: If you still have your install media; I've run the 'check disc for defects' to verify it was perfect (it's easy to do & quick so is good insurance before installs, or on problems). I would also run a memtest of your memory. You've now ruled out added software that wasn't compatible (API/ABI wise).  *I'd probably also open the box & do a cap-check as segfaults can be warning of failing hardware; early problems may need touch, but the program crashes wouldn't be consistent if this was cause; ie. it'd be different programs & unpredictable*

Comment: Before replacing any RAM, show me `sudo lshw -C memory` and `free -h`. Is this a laptop or desktop computer?

Comment: @heynnema I have edited the post. It is a desktop computer used by 2~3 users.

Answer (score 0):

I did not solve the problem completely yet, but I ran memtest82+ and found there were many errors. I think replacing the RAM would be the solution.

Comment: You probably don't have to replace all of the RAM. A good technician can troubleshoot it further and narrow it down. Don't do this yourself.